# Do not return a record during COUNT() operation if there are no results

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to get the how many students are enrolled in a class. The above works if there ARE records.

However, if the there are no results a single "record" is returned where all fields are `NULL` except the `students_count` which returns zero

```
+---+------+------+----------------+----------------+
|   | id   | name | professor_name | students_count |
+---+------+------+----------------+----------------+
| 1 | null | null | null           | 0              |
+---+------+------+----------------+----------------+
```

I would like for there to be NO records returned.

If a record returns it looks like this.

```
+---+----+-------------+----------------+----------------+
|   | id | name        | professor_name | students_count |
+---+----+-------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1 | 1  | Science 101 | Atkins         | 16             |
+---+----+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I have tried variations on the `LEFT JOIN` and a combination of  `IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT students.id), null) AS students_count`

But I can't seem to get it to work.

***Any help?***

```
SELECT  classes.*,
        professors.name AS professor_name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT students.id) AS students_count
FROM classes
INNER JOIN professors ON classes.professor_id = professors.id
LEFT JOIN students ON  classes.id = students.class_id AND classes.class_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE classes.class_id = 3
```

Using the generic data below, with class_id of 3, the result SHOULD be no records. But the `null` record with the count as 0 is returned.

```
+---+------+------+----------------+----------------+
|   | id   | name | professor_name | students_count |
+---+------+------+----------------+----------------+
| 1 | null | null | null           | 0              |
+---+------+------+----------------+----------------+
```

Using the class_id of 1 will return:

```
+---+----+-------------+----------------+----------------+
|   | id | name        | professor_name | students_count |
+---+----+-------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1 | 1  | Science 101 | Atkins         | 4              |
+---+----+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

**Generic Data**

Classes

```
+---+-------------+---------------+
|   | name        | professors_id |
+---+-------------+---------------+
| 1 | Science 101 | 1             |
+---+-------------+---------------+
| 2 | Math        | 2             |
+---+-------------+---------------+
| 3 | English     | 3             |
+---+-------------+---------------+
```

Professors

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Atkins |
+----+--------+
| 2  | Button |
+----+--------+
| 3  | Castor |
+----+--------+
```

Students

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id | name  | classes_id |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  | Adam  | 1          |
+----+-------+------------+
| 2  | Beth  | 1          |
+----+-------+------------+
| 3  | Chris | 1          |
+----+-------+------------+
| 4  | David | 1          |
+----+-------+------------+
| 5  | Erma  | 2          |
+----+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `OUTER JOIN`, because of `LEFT JOIN` will base on `classes` table.

```
SELECT  classes.*,
        professors.name AS professor_name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT students.id) AS students_count
FROM classes
INNER JOIN professors ON classes.professor_id = professors.id
INNER JOIN students ON  classes.id = students.class_id
WHERE classes.class_id = 3
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpqp84tk9Mv7dadBU4LF35/1)

**EDIT**

`HAVING` clause is for aggregate function condition. but you use `HAVING classes.class_id IS NOT NULL` that can move to `where`

```
SELECT  classes.*,
        professors.name AS professor_name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT students.id) AS students_count
FROM classes
INNER JOIN professors ON classes.professor_id = professors.id
LEFT JOIN students ON  classes.id = students.class_id 
WHERE classes.class_id = 3 AND classes.class_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Check the question now please. I updated the statement with the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @user-44651 I edit my answer `HAVING` clause is for aggregate function condition, I think you can move `classes.class_id IS NOT NULL` to `where` clause  you will get the same result, But in your case I would use `INNER JOIN` instead of `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: That doesn't work either. It still returns the single `null` record with students_count column as 0.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for your question, let me check it out

Comment: @user-44651 If use `inner join` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpqp84tk9Mv7dadBU4LF35/1 it can work like your expect. return nothing.

Comment: I appreciate you're effort! That was it!